# SQL oracle - update one column based on multie condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update a records based on multiple condition. My update ignores conditions (and updates for all records where doctype = 7).

```
UPDATE DOCUMENTS SET DOCTYPE = '2'
Where DOCTYPE IN (Select C.DOCTYPE
From
    CLIENTS A,
    AGREEMENTS B,
    DOCUMENTS C
where
    A.ID = B.CUSTOMERID
    and B.ID = C.AGREEMENTID
    and C.STATUS = 1
    and B.STATUS = 1
    and A.STATUS = 1
    and C.DOCTYPE = '7')
```

But select on itself returns what i want. What i did wrong in update?

Comment: Run the sub-query select stand-alone. Does the update make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter based on Documents.ID , try like below:

```
UPDATE DOCUMENTS SET DOCTYPE = '2'
Where ID IN (Select C.ID
From
    CLIENTS A,
    AGREEMENTS B,
    DOCUMENTS C
where
    A.ID = B.CUSTOMERID
    and B.ID = C.AGREEMENTID
    and C.STATUS = 1
    and B.STATUS = 1
    and A.STATUS = 1
    and C.DOCTYPE = '7')
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to co-relate your target table "DOCUMENTS" with sub-query. Try below and check it, hopefully, solves your issues.

```
UPDATE DOCUMENTS S SET DOCTYPE = '2'
Where (DOCTYPE,AGREEMENTID) IN (Select C.DOCTYPE,C.AGREEMENTID
From
    CLIENTS A,
    AGREEMENTS B,
    DOCUMENTS C
where
    A.ID = B.CUSTOMERID
    and B.ID = C.AGREEMENTID
    and C.STATUS = 1
    and B.STATUS = 1
    and A.STATUS = 1
    and C.DOCTYPE = '7')
and S.STATUS = 1
and S.DOCTYPE = '7'
```